# Jar doesn't run on any other enviornment

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have a java program which uses a 3rd party jar. When I compile/run my java code, I need to manually specify the class path in both javac and java commands. I then created a jar file to share with my team. In order for the jar file to work, I had to manually add a class path to the `manifest.mf` file.

Now I have shared the jar file with my team members and the program is not working on their machines. Any ideas on how I can get the jar file to work on their machines? I need to deliver this project as a .jar file. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am working on a linux/ubuntu environment.

Comment: If you want to distribute a *single* jar then you'd need to either create an über-jar, or use a class loader that'll load from jars and embed the jars. Or distribute a complete package with a shell script/batch file launcher.

Comment: Is it possible to use uber-jar in linux? I'm just using "jar" command to create my jar file.

Comment: Make sure you are supplying all the dependent Jars, in the required structure as specified by the class path in the manifest

Comment: @DaveNewton and MadProgrammer - Thanks for your advice, it worked. I had to step away from the jar approad and I ended up creating a wrapper script that used the "java -cp" command and I had to supply all the dependent jars in the command. Again, thanks much!